# mysql from windows cmd opens old version

Tags: mysql, cmd

I use windows and I have previously installed mysql 5.5 for some legacy project, and now I want to use 5.7 for a new one, so I installed 5.7 in another directory, on another port and having different data  directory, my problem is when i launch mysql from cmd like:

```
W:\MySQL57\bin> mysql -u root -p
```

It results in this:

```
W:\MySQL57\bin>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: *****
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 3
Server version: 5.5.54-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

And I am definitely sure that MySQL57 is directory for 5.7 MySQL, so what's wrong with mysql command line tool and how can i fix it to be able to use both mysqls in cmd?

Comment: quite simply, the server it is connecting to is your old server. The application used by the console to connect to the database is the same between versions. Check to make sure your 5.5 database service is disabled, and your 5.7 service is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql command you are using is probably the 5.7 version, you can check this with :

```
W:\MySQL57\bin>mysql -v
```

But this is just the client !

The problem is your server version, you may have 2 versions running (5.5 and 5.7), and as you haven't specified the port you are using the default one which is used by the first server (5.5). 
Try to find the port for the second version (3307 ?) or kill the 5.5 server when you are connecting to the 5.7.

Comment: Thank you! hint about port worked, defined specified port for 5.7 and it opens the right one

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the default mysql set in Environment Variable. If you want to use a specific mysql, you need to provide the path too

```
W:\MySQL57\bin>"W:\MySQL57\bin\mysql" -u root -p
```

In case of `mysql` not working, you can call `mysqld`.

If you want mysql 5.7 to be default, just change it from Environment Variable https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/mysql-installation-windows-path.html

Comment: Not working, old one is still loading, also i have previously changed environment variable and upon calling `mysql --version` it show 5.7, yet launching open the old one